# I changed my application bundle identifier in iOS. Do I now need to create a new provisioning profile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a bit confused about this and would appreciate some advice on how to do this with XF.

Comment: yes.  just update the value in info.plist of your iOS project

Comment: Hi Jason,  Actually the only thing I did was change that in the info.plist.   So would the next step be to create a new provisioning profile and download that etc?

Comment: go to the Apple Developer Portal and create a new provisioning profile and download it

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would need to:

- Go to the Apple Developer portal into the Certificates & Profiles section
- Go to Identifiers and create a new App with the new Bundle Identifier
- Update your old Provisioning profiles you had created to point to the new "App Id"
- Download and Double tap to install it. You might have to restart Visual Studio

I would also recommend you to:

- Open Keychain Access and find the Certificates (dev & prod) you used to create the Provisioning profile
- Right click on it and export it as a P12 file using a password you create
- Store that certificate (with the password), along with the new provisioning profile. You will need these 3 to build the app on a different/formatted Mac, otherwise you will have to recreate Certificates and reassociate the Provisioning profiles to that certificate

Answer (score 0):

> I changed my application bundle identifier in iOS. Do I now need to
> create a new provisioning profile?

Yes, you need to create a new provisioning profile.

You can see the step 3 in [Creating and Using Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios#creating-and-using-certificates),  `you will be able to enter the description and a Bundle Identifier for the app ID`.

Each provisioning profile matches the corresponding bundle ID. When you changed the bundle ID, you need a new provisioning profile.